# Browsersync - How to choose which installation of browser to run?

Tags: firefox, gulp, browser-sync

I've just installed [Firefox Dev Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), and I don't know how to tell `browsersync` to start with it when I launch it.

I know there is the `browser` option in which I can specify "firefox", but how can I differenciate one FF installation from one other ?

The issue would be the same if I had various regular FF installed (eg a 3.5, a 48.x and a 50.x).

I can always open manually the right FF and load the page after browsersync started, but I would like it to do it manually (and not to be opened in my regular non-dev FF).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, it was quite easy: if you put the absolute path to an executable file in the browser option, it takes it smoothly.

So options should be something like :

```
{ port: 9000,
    server: {
      baseDir: [...
      ],
      routes: {
        '/bower_components': 'bower_components',
        '/node_modules': 'node_modules',
        '/temp': 'temp'
      }
    },
    logLevel: 'info',
    notify: true,
    browser: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe',
    reloadDelay: 0 //1000
}
```